# Add a class to the body - PHP Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, class

I am trying to add a class to the body in a WordPress theme so that when there are no posts on a page it will not show the search bar. I have in my `functions.php` right now this to look for one certain page, and if there are no posts.

```
<?php
add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_class' );
function custom_class( $classes ) {
    if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'agent') !== false ){
        $classes[] = 'noSearchBar';
    }
    if(!have_posts() ){
      $classes[] = 'noSearchBar';
    }
    return $classes;
}
?>
```

Which works for most of the pages, but on some pages it is using a different template so instead of calling the posts with `have_posts` like this:

```
<?php
   global $wp_query;

   if ( have_posts() ) :
       while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

           get_template_part('template-parts/property-for-listing');

       endwhile;
       wp_reset_postdata();
   else:
       ?>
<h4><?php esc_html_e('Sorry No Results Found', 'houzez') ?></h4>
<?php
   endif;
   ?>
```

Its is bringing it up like this:

```
<?php
   global $wp_query, $paged;
   if(!$fave_prop_no){
       $posts_per_page  = 9;
   } else {
       $posts_per_page = $fave_prop_no;
   }
   $latest_listing_args = array(
       'post_type' => 'property',
       'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
       'paged' => $paged,
       'post_status' => 'publish'
   );

   $latest_listing_args = apply_filters( 'houzez_property_filter', $latest_listing_args );

   $latest_listing_args = houzez_prop_sort ( $latest_listing_args );
   $wp_query = new WP_Query( $latest_listing_args );

   if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
       while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();

           get_template_part('template-parts/property-for-listing');

       endwhile;
   else:
       get_template_part('template-parts/property', 'none');
   endif;
   ?>
```

Which is making my function not work. There is only 1 line of code in the `template-parts/property-none` and its just saying the same thing the other files are. So I'm not sure why the other template would not add the body class.

Comment: because in WordPress each page is also stored as a post, so if you will check for have_post. I think it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this example,

```
<?php
add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_class' );
function custom_class( $classes ) {
  if ( is_single('post') ) {
     $classes[] = 'SearchBar';
  }else{
     $classes[] = 'noSearchBar';
  }
  return $classes;
}
?>
```

The following example will work for single post page. For more conditions.[visit](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

Hope this will helps you.